# Delete an element from a node list in c

Tags: c, list, nodes, singly-linked-list

This is my struct:

```
struct Node {
    String value; // dynamically allocated string, release memory!
    struct Node* next; // self-reference
};
typedef struct Node Node;
```

Now I need a function which can remove elements of the list.

```
Node* remove_list(Node* list, int index) {}
```

I know how it should work. But I have no idea how to put it in a code...

This is an idea of me:

```
        Node *tmp = list->next;
        list->next = list->next->next;
        free_list (tmp);
        return list;
```

This code removes the 2nd element of an list, but only when the list is not longer than 2 elements... 
If there are more than 2 elements the following error is in the terminal:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

The function should remove the element at index `i`..

I don't have any idea how to make it.

Comment: Did you try searching at all? We have thousands of questions about the basics of linked lists. Plus, if you get a segfault, you should (A) specify exactly when and (B) learn to use a debugger to step through the code, checking variable values, to the point of failure, then get a backtrace from that point and figure out what might be going wrong.

Comment: `list->next->next;` can fail if `list->next` is the last element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
list->next = list->next->next;
```

In your case as you didn't do `NULL` check - you have dereferrenced NULL leading you to Undefined behavior (In your case segmentation fault). (In case `list->next = NULL`).

Also why using the recursion here? Simply a `for` loop will get the job done.

For example,

```
Node* remove_list(Node* list, int index) {
    if(index < 0 ){
       fprintf(stderr,"Error in index\n");
       exit(1);
    }
    if(!list){
       fprintf(stderr,"Empty list\n"); 
       return list;
    }
    Node *p=list,*st =list;
    for(int i = 0; i <= index-1 ; i++){
      if(list) {
          p = list; 
          list = list->next;
      }
      else{
          fprintf(stderr,"Error in index - out of bound access\n");
          exit(1);
      }
    }
    if(index)
       p->next = list->next;
    else
       p = list->next;
    free(list);
    return index == 0? p: st; 
}
```

Comment: 1. If a `for` loop will get the job done, why mention recursion 2. The question is about removing one element from a list, not to free memory from all elements in the list.

Comment: @crashmstr.: I got the question wrong. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

The function can be defined as it is shown in the demonstrative program.
Pay attention to that the allocated string also should be deleted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char * String;

struct Node 
{
    String value; // dynamically allocated string, release memory!
    struct Node *next; // self-reference
};

typedef struct Node Node;

Node * remove_list( Node *list, size_t index )
{
    Node **current = &list;

    while ( *current && index ) 
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
        --index;
    }

    if ( *current )
    {
        Node *tmp = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;

        free( tmp->value );
        free( tmp );
    }

    return list;
}

Node * push( Node *list, const char *value )
{
    Node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );

    tmp->value = malloc( strlen( value ) + 1 );
    strcpy( tmp->value, value );

    tmp->next = list;

    return tmp;
}

void display( Node *list )
{
    for ( ; list; list = list->next )
    {
        printf( "%s ", list->value );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    Node *list = NULL;
    char value[] = "A";

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 'Z' - 'A' + 1; i++ )
    {
        list = push( list, value );
        ++value[0];
    }


    display( list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    list = remove_list( list, 25 );
    display( list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    list = remove_list( list, 0 );
    display( list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    list = remove_list( list, 10 );
    display( list );
    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Z Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
Z Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B 
Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B 
Y X W V U T S R Q P N M L K J I H G F E D C B
```

Or here is another demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef char * String;

struct Node 
{
    String value; // dynamically allocated string, release memory!
    struct Node *next; // self-reference
};

typedef struct Node Node;

Node * remove_list( Node *list, size_t index )
{
    Node **current = &list;

    while ( *current && index ) 
    {
        current = &( *current )->next;
        --index;
    }

    if ( *current )
    {
        Node *tmp = *current;
        *current = ( *current )->next;

        free( tmp->value );
        free( tmp );
    }

    return list;
}

Node * push( Node *list, const char *value )
{
    Node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( Node ) );

    tmp->value = malloc( strlen( value ) + 1 );
    strcpy( tmp->value, value );

    tmp->next = list;

    return tmp;
}

void display( Node *list )
{
    for ( ; list; list = list->next )
    {
        printf( "%s ", list->value );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    Node *list = NULL;
    char value[] = "A";

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 'Z' - 'A' + 1; i++ )
    {
        list = push( list, value );
        ++value[0];
    }

    while ( list )
    {
        display( list );
        putchar( '\n' );
        list = remove_list( list, 0 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

At this time the program output might look like

```
Z Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
N M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
M L K J I H G F E D C B A 
L K J I H G F E D C B A 
K J I H G F E D C B A 
J I H G F E D C B A 
I H G F E D C B A 
H G F E D C B A 
G F E D C B A 
F E D C B A 
E D C B A 
D C B A 
C B A 
B A 
A
```

On the other hand the function interface is not good. It is better when the function reports whether it deleted the given node or did not.

So I myself would declare the function like

```
int remove_list( Node **list, size_t index );
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!

But why I can't remove the first element?

If I choose the index as 0, there is an error..

Comment: @Nicooost This has nothing common with the function implementation I showed. See the error in your own code.